# How to declare private function in inherited javascript class

Tags: javascript

I really like javascript class inheritance described in [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) articale.
Example:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    
  init: function(isDancing){
    this.dancing = isDancing;  
  },  
  dance: function(){
    return this.dancing;
  }

});
```

In this case dance is public function. I want to declare private function "walk". But how and where?
I`m sure it is easy for most of you.

Thank you.

Comment: "Private" properties and prototype inheritance don't work well together. JS has no concept of private properties (yet), so don't try to use the language in way it was not meant to be used.

Comment: John Resig's `Class` implementation has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery!!

Comment: Why should `walk` become private? Private to what? Can you show us what you need it to be, and where you want to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can make private functions, but you lose the ability to prototype:

```
var Person = Class.extend((function () {
    var dancing;

    // private functions
    function dance () {
        return dancing;
    }

    // public functions
    return {
        init: function(isDancing) {
            dancing = isDancing;  
        }
    }
}())); // <-- immediate invocation
```

Comment: I didn't have a close look at the `Class` code, but I think all instances will now share the same `dancing` variable.

Comment: Awesome! I guess I made a static private variable :D

Comment: @Yoshi I could, but I don't want to. The extra parenthesis are there to indicate to the reader that 20 lines down I'm doing immediate invocation. The extra parenthesis are 100% intentional.